# How to get all rows and columns in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a table like this:

```
Name        Places          Sex           Score
-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-
Ken         null            Male          9.5
Smith       London          Male          7.5
Joe         null            null          8.0
```

I want to get all values of a table in Web using Selenium.

How to get values and show data in the table with columns and rows in above table?

My code to do this:

```
List<IWebElement> result = new List<IWebElement>();
IList<IWebElement> tableRows = browser.FindElements(By.XPath("id('column2')/tbody/tr"));

foreach (IWebElement rows in tableRows)
{
    try
    {
        if (rows.FindElements(By.XPath("td")).Count == 10)
            result.Add(rows);
    }
}
```

And I only get all text of rows like this:

```
Ken     Male      9.5
Smith   London    Male      7.5
Joe     8.0
```

As you can see, I only get only rows. And I can't know corresponding value column.

`Joe                                   8.0` is not matched with:

`Name       Places         Sex         Score`.

The HTML Markup of my table:

```
<div class="tabbox_F" id="oTableContainer_L">
   <table id="column2">
      <thead>
         <tr class="tabthdwn">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Places</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>Score</th>\
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr class="table Alpha">
            <td>
                 <div class="name"><span>Ken</span></div>
                 <div class= "category"><span>Student</span></div>
            </td>
            <td><div class="address"></div></td>
            <td><div class="sex"><h5>Male</h5></div></td>
            <td>
                 <div class="score_math"><b>9.5</b></div>
                 <div class="score_bio"><b>7.5</b></div>ư
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="table Alpha">
            <td>
                 <div class="name"><span>Joe</span></div>
                 <div class= "category"><span>Teacher</span></div>
            </td>
            <td><div class="address"></div></td>
            <td><div class="sex"></div></td>
            <td>
                 <div class="score_math"><b>8.0</b></div>
                 <div class="score_bio"><b>5.5</b></div>ư
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be more useful to show us the actual markup of the table.

Comment: @JeffMercado I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at only the TDs, you aren't taking advantage of all the info you have in the HTML. Each TD has a class which tells you which bit of info is contained in each TD, e.g. `<td class="name">` contains the name. Use that to your advantage to separate the different bits of data.

I would do something like this. I added the Values class to store the data for the row temporarily. If you don't need to reuse the data other than to just dump the values, you can just remove that bit.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver();
        List<IWebElement> result = new List<IWebElement>();
        IList<IWebElement> tableRows = browser.FindElements(By.XPath("id('column2')/tbody/tr"));
        By nameLocator = By.ClassName("td > div.name");
        By addressLocator = By.ClassName("td > div.address");
        By sexLocator = By.ClassName("td > div.sex");
        By scoretextLocator = By.ClassName("td > div.score_text");

        // String.Format Method https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa331875(v=vs.71).aspx
        Console.WriteLine("{0,10}{1,10}{2,10}{3,10}",  "Name",  "Address",  "Sex",  "Score");
        foreach (IWebElement rows in tableRows)
        {
            Values values = new Values();
            values.name = rows.FindElement(nameLocator).Text.Trim();
            values.address = rows.FindElement(addressLocator).Text.Trim();
            values.sex = rows.FindElement(sexLocator).Text.Trim();
            values.scoretext = rows.FindElement(scoretextLocator).Text.Trim();

            Console.WriteLine("{0,10}{1,10}{2,10}{3,10}", values.name, values.address, values.sex, values.scoretext);
        }
    }
}

class Values
{
    public string name;
    public string address;
    public string sex;
    public string scoretext;

    public Values()
    {
        this.name = "";
        this.address = "";
        this.sex = "";
        this.scoretext = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, @jeffC. I updated my question. <td> not contains any class. The child of <td> having class. Your code is right at: `By scoretextLocator = By.ClassName("td/div.score_text");`?

Comment: OK. I updated my answer to match the update to the question. Did you try this? Did it work for you?

Comment: I tried with other method base on your answer and this resolve my problem. Thanks, @jeffC

Answer (score 1):

Why not this way:

```html
List<IWebElement> result = new List<IWebElement>();
IList<IWebElement> tableRows = browser.FindElements(By.XPath("id('column2')/tbody/tr"));

foreach (IWebElement rows in tableRows)
{
    IList<IWebElement> allColumns =row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
    //and how allColumns[0] +1 etc .... gives you each values, including nulls
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only issue is how you're printing out your rows.  Notice that some of the columns have no values.  If you are not handling that in your output, then it will come out the way you've shown us above.  If you use a debugger and look at the row element, you will likely find that there are still 4 td children in each row.

Comment: I can't know rows have null values. Are you know handling my output? The output only gets all text in rows. How to add header is columns to this values in rows?

Comment: You CAN know if rows have null values... you just may not be using that info and may need to rewrite your output writer to take advantage of that info. You'd have to put more of that code in the question if you want feedback on that.